# node.js/express chaining multiple get commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route I that in order to get all the data needs to access the API server multiple times (according to the data that was given).

Now I need to add a third access to the server and it's getting rather unreadable.
The following code is working, but I have a feeling I'm not doing it right (promises?) - couldn't figure out what exactly is recommended in this case

The code: (stripped down to emphasise the point)

```
router.get('/', function(req, main_response) {
        http.get(FIRST_API_COMMAND, function (res) {
            var moment_respose_content = '';
            res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                moment_respose_content += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end',function(){
                if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode > 299) {
                    main_response.send('error in getting moment');
                    return;
                }
                var response = JSON.parse(moment_respose_content );
                if (response.success)
                {
                    var data = response.data;
                    //doing something with the data
                    http.get(SECOND_API_COMMAND, function (res) {
                        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                            comment_respose_content += chunk;
                        });

                        res.on('end',function(){
                            var response = JSON.parse(comment_respose_content);
                            if (response.success)
                            {
                                var comments = response.data;
                                main_response.render('the page', {data: data});
                                return;
                            }
                        });
                    }).on('error', function (e) {
                        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
                        main_response.send('Error in getting comments');
                    });
                    return;
                }
            });
        }).on('error', function (e) {
            console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
            main_response.send('Error in getting moment');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a middleware for each remote action, and then `use` those middlewares before the `get` handler, so the `get` handler can simply access their results. (Promises can help if you need to start subsequent requests before waiting for earlier ones to finish, but that situation is rare.)

For example, using `express` middleware to fetch each remote data independently:

```
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

/* middleware to fetch moment. will only run for requests that `router` handles. */
router.use(function(req, res, next){
    var api_url = 'https://google.com/';
    request.get(api_url, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        req.moment_response = response.headers["date"];
        next();
    });
});

/* middleware to fetch comment after moment has been fetched */
router.use(function(req, res, next){
    var api_url = 'https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=100&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new';
    request.get(api_url, function(err, response, body){
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        req.comment_response = parseInt(body);
        next();
    });
});

/* main get handler: expects data to already be loaded */
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.json({
        moment: req.moment_response,
        comment: req.comment_response
    });
});

/* error handler: will run if any middleware called next() with an argument */
router.use(function(error, req, res, next){
    res.status(500);
    res.send("Error: " + error.toString());
});

app.use('/endpoint', router);

app.listen(8000);
```

Often the remote data you want to fetch is based on some parameter of  the main request. In this case you would want to use [req.param()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param) instead of [App.use()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) to define the data-loading middleware.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it (need to understand it first :))

Comment: wait... get is rendering a page - shouldn't it wait for the previous app.use?

Comment: plus - where is the API server call in your example?

Comment: can you please provide an example with router instead of app, and a call to a remote server using http? I can't seem to adapt your example to it...

Comment: I just used a timeout to mock an API server call. It demonstrates that both asynchronous calls fill in some data before the rendering happens. I'll write a more realistic example.

Comment: After removing the timeout - it worked... I think it is still better to have a realistic example for future reference - Thanks again...

Comment: I've rewritten it to use a router and make actual network calls. Note how the router is mounted at `/endpoint`, so the remote API calls won't be made unless a matching path is requested. If this doesn't fit your use-case, you would want specific logic to control whether to make calls or not.

Comment: Don't forget to call `next()` in every possible code branch. Express will never reach the `get` handler unless some `next()` has been called.